# How to declare date parameter like Start_date,end_date in oracle ? and how to pass it?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

My  query is

```
select  
    '1' as KPI_ID, 'P2P' as KPI_DESC,'22-MAR-17' as dates,
    (sum(case when S_DATE between add_months('22-MAR-17',0)-13
                          and add_months('22-MAR-17',0)-7  then VOLUME else 0 end )) LAST_WEEK_Volume,
    (sum(case when S_DATE between add_months('22-MAR-17',0)-6
                          and add_months('22-MAR-17',0)  then VOLUME else 0 end )) THIS_WEEK_Volume
from 
    table
```

problem statement -actually i have two years old data ..i want calculate last week volume,current week volume day wise for 2 years.so what should i modify in query .current query gives only 1 day calculation .i want to do per day wise calculation.according to google i found  that after defining paramater start_date and end_date and passing to column it can be possible,could u help me out pleasr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use **substitution**

```
        define my_date = '''22-MAR-17''';
         select  
           '1' as KPI_ID, 'P2P' as KPI_DESC, TO_DATE(&my_date,'DD-MON-YY')  as dates,
            (sum(case when S_DATE between add_months(TO_DATE(&my_date,'DD-MON-YY'),0)-13
            and add_months(TO_DATE(&my_date,'DD-MON-YY'),0)-7  then VOLUME else 0 end )) LAST_WEEK_Volume,
            (sum(case when S_DATE between add_months(TO_DATE(&my_date,'DD-MON-YY') ,0)-6
            and add_months(TO_DATE(&my_date,'DD-MON-YY') ,0)  then VOLUME else 0 end )) THIS_WEEK_Volume
            from 
            table;
         undefine my_date;
```

Comment: but probably it will show result for "22-mar-17" date only what should i do for all date between 2015 to 2017

Comment: @siddhesh Your  original question was 'how to declare' a parameter. So, you can declare as shown above `my_start_date` and `my_end_date` and then use those in your sql statement.  What exactly are you asking now?                
(You got me confused here).

Comment: sorry for confusion! actually i have two years old data ..i want  calculate last week volume,current week volume day wise for 2 years.so what should i modify in query .current query gives only 1 day calculation .i want to do per day wise calculation.so what should i do please suggest!

Comment: @siddhesh Actually this sounds like totally different question. Proper thing to do is to accept whichever solution is correct for the current question and then create new one.

Comment: Thanks for Giving solution !

Comment: @siddhesh You are welcome ;-) Now is the time to  post your new question. good luck.

Answer (score 2):

RTFM?

Oracle built-in function `TO_DATE` is what you need.

See Oracle [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions219.htm#SQLRF06132).

```
select TO_DATE(`14-FEB-2018`,`DD-MON-YYYY`) from DUAL
```

UPDATE

In reply to your comment...

> Actually i am new in pl-sql

I suggest (again) RTFM.

Go to the Oracle Database [Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/index.html) Web page and select the appropriate Oracle database version.

Regarding PL/SQL, I suggest [PL/SQL Language Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/index.html)

Comment: Actually i am new in pl-sql.can u tell me how to declaire date paramater & pass it .so my query will be dynamic.and pupose behind dynamic query is i have two years old data ..i want take calculatiate  last week volume,current week volume  day wise for 2 years..